# python UDP socket - recvfrom works, but getpeername() gives "Transport endpoint is not connected" error?

Tags: python, sockets, select, udp

I have a udp server in python that i'm testing out by sending packets with `netcat -u server_ip server_port`

on the udp server, I can receive the packets with
`data,addrport = socket.recvfrom(some_number)` — I can read the data received and see the other socket's address port with `addrport`.

But if I try to use `socket.getpeername()` on the same variable instead it gives the `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected` error.

What causes this? I'm confused as my netcat terminal doesn't close after sending, which I assume means its already connected to my UDP socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can receive the packets with `data,addrport = socket.recvfrom(some_number)`

`recvfrom` means that you are working with an unconnected UDP socket, i.e. the case where a single socket could receive packets from various sources and also send data to various sources using `sendto`. `getpeername` instead expects a connected socket, i.e. one which will only receive data from a single source (using `recv` not `recvfrom`) and only send to a single source (using `send` not `sendto`). This is the case with TCP established sockets (the ones returned by `accept`) but also with UDP socket which are explicitly connected by calling `connect`.

Comment: Thank you! I was very confused as to how UDP sockets mantain a conenction if they're meant to be connectionless

Comment: @cdpp: While `connect` on a TCP socket actually establishes a connection using the TCP handshake (communication involved), a `connect` on a UDP socket just sets the destination address on the socket, i.e. no communication involved. But this setting means that the socket will only receive packets from the given address and will also only send packets to the address.